# Serialize vtkUnstructuredGrid in VTK 8.2.0

Tags: c++, vtk

I am using VTK 8.2.0 and I want to serialize a `vtkUnstructuredGrid` and restore it later.

I find it is easy to get and set its raw points from `vtkPoints`.

But for `vtkCellArray`, I find I have no access to `GetOffsetsArray()` and `GetConnectivityArray()`, but the document says `vtkCellArray` do have these two methods:

https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkCellArray.html

So what is the best way to serialize a `vtkUnstructuredGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vtkDataWriter::WriteToOutputStringOn()
```

https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkDataWriter.html